# Error in import SSIS package in SSDT Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, ssis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekRND.png)I want to import an SSIS package into SSDT Visual Studio 2017 but while doing so I am getting an error i.e. Unable to create the type with name "Azure Storage".(Microsoft.SQlServer.managedDTS). I have installed all the necessary package also in SSIS toolbox Azure content is getting loaded.Please let me know what I am missing.